How to animate an UIView by setting its frame that has auto layout constraints?
I have a UIView subclass called MyView as such
@implementation MyView
{
  UIView<SomeImageProtocol> *_imageView;
}

- (instancetype) init
{
  if (self = super) {
    _imageView = ...
    [self addSubview:_imageView];
  }
}

...
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  _imageView.frame = self.bounds;
}

..

In my MyViewController, I want to trigger some image animation, i.e shrinking in size:
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  _dwellTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(animateView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)animateView
{
  [myView animateOnImage];
}

In MyView class, animation doesn't seem to work when I set _imageView's frames, but when I set its opacity like .alpha or .layer.cornerRadius, it works just fine. The resources I came across online suggested that _imageView has Auto Layout constraints and its frame is still controlled by I have specified in layoutSubviews. The animation seems to always end in Auto Layout.
-(void)animateOnImage {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    [self shrinkImageView];
  }];
}

- (void)shrinkImageView {
  // Doesn't work
  _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 500);
  // Works
  _imageView.alpha = 0.5;
}


You animate the constraints, not the frame

The problem is NOT the auto-layout constraints...
The issue is that setting the frame of a subview in [UIView animateWithDuration:...] triggers a call to layoutSubviews ... where you again set the frame of the subview.
To avoid that, we can add a CGRect property to track self.bounds and, in layoutSubviews, only update _imageView.frame if self.bounds has changed.
Example code...

MyView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyView : UIView
-(void)animateOnImage;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END


MyView.m
#import "MyView.h"

@implementation MyView

{
    UIView *_imageView;
    CGRect myBounds;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _imageView = [UIView new];
        _imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor;
        [self addSubview:_imageView];
        myBounds = CGRectZero;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    
    // debug - log that layoutSubviews was called
    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews");
    
    // only execute the following if self.bounds has changed
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(myBounds, self.bounds)) {
        
        // debug - log that self.bounds has changed
        NSLog(@"self.bounds changed, so set _imageView frame");
        myBounds = self.bounds;
        _imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    }
}

-(void)animateOnImage {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [self shrinkImageView];
    }];
}

- (void)shrinkImageView {
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 150, 200);
    _imageView.alpha = 0.5;
}


@end


AnimSubViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface AnimSubViewController : UIViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END


AnimSubViewController.m
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AnimSubViewController.h"
#import "MyView.h"

@interface AnimSubViewController ()
{
    MyView *myView;
}
@end

@implementation AnimSubViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackgroundColor;
    
    myView = [MyView new];
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellowColor;
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [myView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:120.0],
        [myView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:80.0],
        [myView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-80.0],
        [myView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:-120.0],
    ]];
    
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(animateView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)animateView
{
    [myView animateOnImage];
}

@end




Thank you! but the animation now is shrinking starting from MyView's origin x and y (0,0), then moving toward its final position, instead of shrinking from the center :(

@夢のの夢 -- I added a screen-cap of the animation to my answer. Is that not what you're getting?

unfortunately no, I see you using myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; and NSLayoutConstraints in viewDidLoad I am not using any of these. Not sure if it has anything to do with it.

@夢のの夢 - no, that has nothing to do with it. If you are not using constraints, I don't now why you were talking about them in your post (and post title). Did you run my example code as-is? If not, try it. If you made changes to your code based on my answer, and it's still not working, then post your full, modified code so we can see what's happening.
